# What's the difference between "Stop Debugging" and "Terminate All" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

As the title asks, what's the difference between "Stop Debugging" and "Terminate All" in Visual Studio (I know those options are available in 2008, but not sure if it's called the same or something different in 2005 or 2010) ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think Terminate All will kill all attached processes in Visual Studio while the former just stops debugging but leaves the processes running.

Update: A better answer from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406kfbs1.aspx

> Stop Debugging terminates the process you are debugging if the
>   program was launched from Visual
>   Studio. If you attached to the
>   process, instead of launching it from
>   Visual Studio, the process continues
>   running. If you want to terminate
>   attached processes, you can terminate
>   a single process from the Processes
>   window or terminate all attached
>   process with the Terminate All
>   command.