# Getting Visual Studio Error on debugging "a 64-bit debugging operation is taking longer than expected."

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am getting this error on debugging  Visual Studio 2017 with platform target as 64 bit. Tried many workarounds but nothing worked. Anybody has faced similar issue in the past and knows the workaround, please let me know. Nothing was changed in my machine, no patch, no update.

Tried below workarounds but nothing worked out.

Workaround 1:
1.Run cmd.exe as administrator
2.Type in and run the following commands:
    netsh winsock reset catalog
    netsh int ip reset reset.log hit

Workaround 2:
Switch target platform from x64 to x86 
Build project in x86 
Switch back the target platform to x64.

Workaround 3:
Reninstalled Visual Studio 2017 Professional

[64 bit debugging error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQzZG.png)
Above error is followed by below error on click of terminate button.
[Operation taking longer than expected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x869z.png)
Above error is followed by below one
[Remote debugger closed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXh1s.png)

Comment: Is it a huge project? It often happens to me when debugging Chromium

Comment: Yes it is a huge project.

Comment: I suddenly started seeing this on every solution I opened, but the problem cleared up after restarting the machine.  I'd guess some process running in the background was locked up.

Comment: @AravindS I have the same issue on `VS2019` on my `Windows-10 Professional`. The project is not big and cleaning the solution or restarting the machine makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you didn't set some option that uses external stuff.

In my case (C++, MFC) while debugging external code I set a checkmark to use **"Microsoft Symbol Servers"** (.pdb locations) an forgot about that. The result was that the following starts of debug sessions were incredibly slow (IDE was downloading a lot from MS servers) and I faced mentioned "longer than expected" message. I unchecked that option back via **"Visual Studio 2017"->Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols** and it solved my case.

Answer (score 1):

For somebody maybe still frustrated and struggle with this problem, I don't understand the detail about Visual Studio but I used this solution. I use VS Ultimate 2013 Version 12

#### 1. Using code to exit running program

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995235/whats-the-difference-between-stop-debugging-and-terminate-all-in-visual-stu), I assume that stop debugging leaves some process stuck and locked. Then I use this code to exit my running program

```
int c = cvWaitKey(1);
    if (c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q')
        break;
```

#### 2. Terminate All

You can use this way when your program break. Just click break then Debug -> Terminate All
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQLTm.jpg

#### 3. Close Visual Studio Debugger Monitor

When your program is already locked and the task manager can't end task not responding program windows you can use this way. Close Visual Studio -> Open task manager -> End task your stuck running program window -> find Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor -> end task

Sorry for my bad English, hope it can help you. CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

For me this was happening because script debugging was enabled and chrome was the default browser.  Once I either turned off script debugging or switched to Edge everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I had a previous debug thread still running. I terminated it from the task manager, and everything went back to normal.